# Error in passing dynamic data in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). I have following binding

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    defaultDate: '2017-03-23',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{ "title": "General Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 10:00:00 AM", "end": "3/23/2017, 11:00:00 AM" }, { "title": "Client Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 12:00:00 PM", "end": "3/23/2017, 1:00:00 PM" }]
});
```

Above code worked perfectly.

But when I tried to assign my json to variable and passed that variable to calendar event I got error:

> https://site-url/MyData 404 NOT FOUND

Here, "MyData" is my json data. It got appended with URL and throws above error.

Sample code which I am using

```
var calendarData = [{ "title": "General Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 10:00:00 AM", "end": "3/23/2017, 11:00:00 AM" }, { "title": "Client Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 12:00:00 PM", "end": "3/23/2017, 1:00:00 PM" }];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    defaultDate: '2017-03-23',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: calendarData
});
```

I am unable to trace out the problem. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code with eventSources option. try this.

```
    var calendarData = [{ "title": "General Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 10:00:00 AM", "end": "3/23/2017, 11:00:00 AM" }, { "title": "Client Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 12:00:00 PM", "end": "3/23/2017, 1:00:00 PM" }];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    defaultDate: '2017-03-23',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventSources: [{
         events: calendarData
    }]
});
```

To see example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrpmLbkb/)

Answer (score 1):

try by dynamically adding events

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},

defaultDate: '2017-03-23',
navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events    
 });

 var calendarData = [{ "title": "General Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 10:00:00 AM", "end": "3/23/2017, 11:00:00 AM" }, { "title": "Client Meeting", "start": "3/23/2017, 12:00:00 PM", "end": "3/23/2017, 1:00:00 PM" }];
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', calendarData  );
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your supports. But I got the real mistake.

I was building my array as

```
calendarData.push({"title": bookingInformations[i].Subject, "start": new Date(bookingInformations[i].StartDateTime).toLocaleString(), "end": new Date(bookingInformations[i].EndDateTime).toLocaleString() });
```

I just changed the array build up as following

```
calendarData.push({title: bookingInformations[i].Subject, start: new Date(bookingInformations[i].StartDateTime).toLocaleString(), end: new Date(bookingInformations[i].EndDateTime).toLocaleString()});
```

And it solved the problem.